# Non greedy regex returns wrong result

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to clean an abstract by spotting the texts showing up between a dot and a colon followed by an uppercase character. To do so, I use the regex:

`re.findall(r"\.\s(.*?):\s?[A-Z]", text)` for the text

```
text = 'Background: Flavonoids constitute one of the best-characterized groups of plant secondary metabolites with enormous pharmaceutical potential. A flavone type of plant flavonoid, cirsilineol, has been reported to exhibit proapoptotic effects against malignant human cells. Objectives: The present study was designed to investigate the antiproliferative effects of cirsilineol against human gastric cancer cells. Materials and Methods: Cell viability was assessed by 3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyltetrazolium bromide (MTT) and colony formation assays. Apoptosis was detected by acridine orange/ethidium bromide (AO/EB) and annexin V/propidium iodide (PI) assay. Protein expression was examined by western blotting analysis. Results: The results showed cirsilineol inhibits the proliferation of human gastric cancer cells. The IC50 of cirsilineol against human gastric cancer cells (BGC-823, SGC-7901, and MGC-803) ranged from 8 to 10 mu M. Nonetheless, cirsilineol exhibited comparatively lower antiproliferative effects against normal GES-1 cells. The IC50 of cirsilineol against normal GES-1 cells was found to be 120 mu M. Colony formation assay showed that cirsilineol suppressed the colony formation of BGC-823 and MGC-803 cells in a dose-dependent manner. Acridine orange and ethidium bromide (AO/EB) staining showed that cirsilineol induced apoptosis in BGC-823 and MGC-803 cells. The percentage of apoptosis increased from 7.4% in control to 40.5% in BGC-823 cells and from 6.56% in control to 33.53% in MGC-803 cells at 8 mu M cirsilineol. Western blotting showed cirsilineol caused an increase in Bax and cleaved caspase-3 and a decrease in Bcl-2 expression in both BGC-823 and MGC-803 cells. Conclusion: Together, the results are indicative of the proapoptotic and antitumor potential of cirsilineol against gastric cancer cells, suggestive of its possible therapeutic significance in future.'
```

However, the first extracted pattern is:

```
'A flavone type of plant flavonoid, cirsilineol, has been reported to exhibit proapoptotic effects against malignant human cells. Objectives',
```

while it should be '`Objectives`'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Laziness work only one way - ahead. You should exclude dots from your match: `\.\s([^.]*?):\s?[A-Z]`

Comment: Or better yet `(?<=\.\s)[^.]+(?=:\s?[A-Z])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy modifier means that if matching can stop now it show stop, and not look more. It doesn't affect starting position of matching.

To to what you described, you need to exclude `.` from matching. So your regex in this case will be:

```
\.\s([^.]*?):\s?[A-Z]
```

This way no dots are allowed in your match except for beginning one.

Also, you could use

```
(?<=\.\s)[^.]+(?=:\s?[A-Z])
```

This way result of matching will contain only text between a dot and a colon followed by upper letter, but not those dot, colon and upper letter, if you'll need to use other languages.
For python ***it works both ways***!